# Best way to encrypt data

Tags: encryption, flutter

I want to encrypt/decrypt my data using the [encrypt package](https://pub.dev/packages/encrypt).
But the app takes long time to executing and displaying data to the UI. So I'm looking for a best way to improve my code.

I have created a model like that.

```
 class Users{
    String id;
    String name;
    String surname;        
  }

  Users(
  {this.id, this.name, this.surname});

  Map<String, Object> toMap() => {
    'id': id,
    'name': encryptData(name, key),
    'surname': encryptData(surname,key)
   };

 Users.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> u) {
   id = u['id'];
   name= decryptData(u['name'], key);
   surname= decryptData(u['surname'], key);
 }
```

And I decrypt the data called each time I want to use it as well I encrypt it when I want to store it in the database.
I use the code below for the encryption

```
    String decryptData(String field, List<int> strkey) {
         try {
             final key = Key.fromBase64(base64Encode(Uint8List.fromList(strkey)));
             final iv = IV.fromUtf8('utf8_string');
             final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc));
             final decrypt= encrypter.decrypt(Encrypted.fromBase64(field.base64), iv: iv);     
             return decrypt;
          } catch (Ex) {
             print('DECRYPError===${Ex}');
            return field;
          }
       }



    String encryptData(String field, List<int> strkey) {
         try {
             final key = Key.fromBase64(base64Encode(Uint8List.fromList(strkey)));
             final iv = IV.fromUtf8('utf8_string');
             final encrypter = Encrypter(AES(key, mode: AESMode.cbc));
             final encrypted = encrypter.encrypt(field, iv: iv);     
             return encrypted.base64;
          } catch (Ex) {
             print('CRYPError===${Ex}');
            return field;
          }
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one Data transfer object class in serialisation and transfer the data.

Create one DTO object the serialisation and deserialization will take care of encryption and decryption of data

Declare private data members and public setter and getter methods in that DTO class.  Also parameterized constructor.